# How to replace space character (' ') with comma in c++?

Tags: c++, string, replace, str-replace

How to replace all space characters (' ') with commas (,) in a string in c++.

This is what I tried.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    replace(a.begin(), a.end(), ' ', ',');
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

But when I enter something like this for example
(stack overflow)
it only returns (stack) for some reason.

Can someone correct the code please?

Comment: Your replacement code is correct, but cin stops reading at the first white space. Try using getline instead.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: Replace `cin >> a;` with `getline(cin, a)` so that you read in the full string. (cin stops at white space)

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, why don't you post this as an answer also.

Comment: We don't need to repeat the same answer all over the place.  This question has been asked and answered before so it's policy to close it as a duplicate.